# Swift - MapKit - How to draw a line

Tags: mapkit

Xcode 11.1, Swift 4

How to draw a line between three locations (points) using Mapkit in Swift?

```
let london = Capital(title: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), info: "Home to the 2012 Summer Olympics.")

let oslo = Capital(title: "Oslo", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.95, longitude: 10.75), info: "Founded over a thousand years ago.")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To connect any number of points you can use [`MKPolyline`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpolyline#) and its [`MKPolylineRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpolylinerenderer#) view. First you add the overlay to your map, then provide the view with visual settings for the polyline in the delegate method:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

struct Capital {
  let title: String
  let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
  let info: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self

    let london = Capital(title: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), info: "Home to the 2012 Summer Olympics.")
    let oslo = Capital(title: "Oslo", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.95, longitude: 10.75), info: "Founded over a thousand years ago.")

    mapView.addOverlay(MKPolyline(coordinates: [london.coordinate, oslo.coordinate], count: 2))
  }

  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: overlay as! MKPolyline)
    polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.black
    polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 4.0
    return polylineRenderer
  }
}
```

Here is the result of the code above:
[image: Simulator screenshot]